# pin new email or new task to start screen possible?

Tags: pin-to-start

Is it possible to pin a shortcut to the start screen for: create a new mail and/or create a new outlook task. Maybe through a third party app?

Comment: It's not possible natively. The rest of the question falls under the category of "app recommendations."

Answer (score 1):

It it not possible natively. as @RareNCool said, but you can search for third party apps in Store, they might allow you to do so.